# Do OpenGL texture coordinates have to be within range 0-1

Tags: opengl

For example, if I am using `glTexCoord3f(GLfloat s,GLfloat t,GLfloat r)`, paramesters `s`, `t`, `r` are supposed to be within the range of `0.0f` and `1.0f`. But I am wonder whether it will be okay for us to set some values which are beyond this range?

The motivation for doing this is that if I am trying to visualize the cross section of a cube as shown in the following image. The red rectangle 'abcd' is the cross section I am trying to visualize. But I notice that the coordinates of the green rectangle 'ABCD' is a lot easier to get (especially when the plane is not perpendicular to any axis).

[image: Visualization of the cross section of a cube]

---

I just give that a try. It seems that there is no problem what so ever. But I am still a little bit worry about that though. I don't know whether it is good practice to do so. Whether this is supported by all sort of graphic cards?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

OpenGL texture coordiates may be arbitrary values. They will however be clamped, or repeated/wrapped into the range 0…1 depending on the texture coordinate wrap or clamp settings.

Also some texture targets treat texture coordinates differently. GL_TEXTURE_xD behave as one would expect. GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP takes the texture coordinate to be a direction vector. GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY treats the S and T components as usual, but the R component as a layer index. GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE treats the texture coordinates as pixel indices into the texture image.

Comment: I am surprised you did not mention `GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE`... that is the first thing that comes to my mind when I think of textures that do not follow the normal rules when it comes to texture coordinates.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman: Whoopsy, completely forgot about that one. However it's been a very long time I used it the last time.